# VBA Word - Document.Words doesn't recognize ID

Tags: regex, string, vba, ms-word, find

My Problem: I want to look for IDs in a Word Document which is something like " RS.1234/56.78910 "

My Code:

```
Sub findIDs()

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim obj_RegEx As Object
    Dim nextID As String

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set obj_RegEx = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")
    obj_RegEx.Pattern = "RS.[0-9]{4;4}/[0-9]{2;2}.[0-9]{5;5}"

    For i = 1 To oDoc.Words.Count
        If obj_RegEx.Test(oDoc.Words.Item(i).Text) = True Then
            Debug.Print "Found: " & oDoc.Words.Item(i).Text
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not Found: " & oDoc.Words.Item(i).Text
      End If
   Next

End Sub
```

My Problem: Imho the RegExp seems to be fine BUT the Words.Count/Words.item split the ID into 7 words like:

```
RS.1234/56.78910" -> "RS" "." "1234" "/" "56" "." "78910"
```

Why not using " Document.Range.Find " ? -> I want to save the words to a variable and find the highest ID and I have no idea how to do this with `range.find`

Comment: How do you want to split it?

Comment: I don't want to split it at all -> I want to find the ID with my regexp but document.words splits the ID into 7 strings and my regexp finds nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through the whole document text instead of words.

Another thing, your Regexp doesn't work: you need to escape dots, and `{4,4}` should be `{4}`

```
Sub findIDs()

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim obj_RegEx As Object
    Dim nextID As String
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim id As Variant

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set obj_RegEx = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")
    obj_RegEx.Global = True 'match all occurrences
    obj_RegEx.Pattern = "RS\.[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{5}"

    Set result = obj_RegEx.Execute(oDoc.Content.Text)
    For Each id In result
            Debug.Print "Found: " & id.value
   Next

End Sub
```